# Customizing the autogenerated index view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

There's a demo MVC project that I'm working on. I used Entity framework 5.0 to create a entity data model named "EmployeeDataModel". knowing that all classes within 
that entity is AutoGenerated (and cannot be changed)and I wanted to change little things about the model I decided to created a "EditModel" folder which I guess this is what "EditModel" is for. then I created a Parent class within that folder and I copied pretty much everything within auto generated Employee.cs class. then I created a controller class with exactly same code of Index method of the EmployeeController and exact same view except this will be hard coded to use the Parent Model class and not the MVCDemo.Models.Employee.

however when I try to run the page I'm getting this error ;

(The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCDemo.Models.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent]')

which means my view is expecting a list of object but it is receiving one object .
and if I delete the "IEnumerable" part of my View and just let it be                  "@model MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent" it will pass this error but the fact that I'm waiting for a list to loop through is still there ! in my Controller I'm sending a list back to the View "return View(employees.ToList());"

plus when I'm creating the view if I choose the Employee Model which is a built in Model the page will run without any problem.  I cannot find any indication in the Employee.cs class that if it returns a list !

please help me understand this.

This is my Employee.cs (auto generated class)

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This is my Index View ;

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.DepName )
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DepName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmployeeId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmployeeId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My Parent class within the EditModel folder ;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MVCDemo.Models;
namespace MVCDemo.EditModels
{
    public class Parent
    {

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EmployeeController ;

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();

        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult EmployeeParent()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);

            return View(employees.ToList());

        }
```

and the Employeeparent View;

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeParent";
}

<h2>EmployeeParent</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns a `List<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>`, but the view is expecting and `IEnumerable<MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent>`...

```
var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
```

There are 2 ways to fix this...

1) Change the type of the model that view is expecting...

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCDemo.Models.Employee>
```

2) Or change the query to return a list of `MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent`s...

```
using MVCDemo.EditModels;
// ...
public ActionResult EmployeeParent()
{
    var parents = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department)
                        .Select(e => new Parent 
                             { 
                                 EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                                 Name = e.Name,
                                 Gender = e.Gender,
                                 City = e.City,
                                 DepartmentId = e.DepartmentId,
                                 Department = e.Department
                             });
    return View(parents.ToList());
}
```

If your goal is to make changes to the generated `Employee` class that was generated by Entity Framework, EF actually generates the model as a partial class, so you can add to it by creating a partial class and it won't be overwritten when the models regenerate. For example...

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm kind of new to the concept of MVC so I really don't understand the difference between the Model class that I've written with the auto generated one ! the original querry is also returning a list hence the view is expecting IEnumerable but it is working just fine ! but not with my code ?

Comment: The problem is not that it's a List (List implements IEnumerable so there's no problems there), the problem is the type of objects inside the list. You are returning a list of Employees but the view is expecting a list of Parents.

Comment: I see thanks ! I tried to insert the code you gave me Number '2' in my Controller and I am getting a compiler error ; "Cannot initialize type 'MVCDemo.EditModels.Parent' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' "

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake when typing that up. Corrected now! :)

Comment: thank you so much wish I could vote for your respond but I don't have enough reputation !

Comment: Anthony ! all I wanted to was to change the column name of my view in the tutorial that I'm following. the instructor had used a method, however I was unable to use the same that I explained . I would be happy if you take a look at it ! I added the part 2 to the code above !